# Extending zinnia

Tags: django, zinnia

I am trying to edit the template for Zinnia but I don't know where pip install zinnia. I used this installation instruction from the website. I tried find and locate but couldn't find it.

$ pip install django-blog-zinnia

Any ideas?

Comment: You don't need to edit the template in the zinnia package, you can simply overwrite it in your project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a virtual environment it will be installed in the python2.x/site-packages/.

If you are not using a virtual environment it will be installed in the same place under your /lib/ folder.

I have modified Zinnia a great deal, and I just brought it out of the site-packages into my django project to be on hand.

Comment: Yeah I found it under /Users/xxx/.virtualenvs/tutorial/lib/python2.7/site-packages/